# Why Humans can't carry themselves?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram

I have been lately questioning why if someone carries you can't carry him at the same time. basically, I don't really know if it's possible at least physically and not limited by humans abilities. What I can tell by intuitive that they can't because humans can't carry themselves so they can't carry themselves and some extra mass but, this is not a proof and am not sure about anything yet.

My questions are:

**1-** Can a human carry himself theoretically? you can suppose that a human hand are so powerful?

**2-** Can you provide such an intuitive explanation?

**3-** Can you provide such a mathematical-physical proof for your answer?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68629/2451

Comment: It is generelly advised to focus your question as much as possible. I would however, in this case say that it is fine since your three questions cover the same main question

Comment: I seriously don't understand what you mean. Do you mean to ask if humans can fly?

Comment: You're already "carrying yourself" when you walk anywhere.

Comment: Strongly agree with @DavidWhite's comment. It would be good for you to edit this post and explain what you mean by "carry himself" using physics concepts/terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comes down to the difference between internal and external forces on a body.

A system can only accelerate (i.e. being lifted), when there are external forces on a body. This is essentially Newton's second law of motion. If you carry yourself, this is an internal force, which won't lift you.

You can also look at it using Newton's third law. So, you try to lift yourself with your arm, pulling you up from your ass. At the same time, your ass exerts an equal and opposite force on your hand. So your body is pulling you down. Also in the ISS in the absence of gravitational forces, this is not possible.